# mysql/python connector using a params and a dictionary dying when handling a null value

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv, null

```
insert_statement = ("INSERT INTO mydb.sets_ledger "
    "( exercise, weight, reps, rpe) "
    "VALUES ( %(Exercise)s, %(weight)s, %(reps)s, %(rpe)s")

#import the CSV file
workout_file = "squat_rpe.csv"
file_hook = open(workout_file, 'rb')
dictionary=csv.DictReader(file_hook)

print dictionary.dialect
print dictionary.fieldnames

for row in dictionary:
    print row['Day'], row['Exercise'], row['weight'], row['reps'], row['rpe']
    print "==> "
    cursor.execute(insert_statement, row)
```

Is crashing when I feed it a row from the dictionary where one of the columns (in this case 'rpe' column is empty.)

```
row =    {'rpe': '', 'weight': '60', 'reps': '3', 'Day': '04/26/14', 'Exercise': 'Competition Back Squat’}
```

gives me final error

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

The mysql schema for rpe, reps, weight are all decimal(10,5)

How to use the dictionary/params method of generating the sql queries when you have empty values sprinkled around the data?

===================================

I built a separate test:

```
import csv
import mysql.connector

#engage the MySql Table
cnx= mysql.connector.connect(user='root', host='127.0.0.1', database='mydb')
cursor = cnx.cursor()


insert_statement_dic = ("INSERT INTO mydb.sets_ledger "
    "( exercise, rpe) "
    "VALUES ( %(exercise)s, %(rpe)s)")

insert_statement_tuple = ("INSERT INTO mydb.sets_ledger "
    "( exercise, rpe) "
    "VALUES ( %s, %s)")

tuple_param_10 = ('tuple insert test 10', 10)
tuple_param_pure_none = ('tuple insert test None', None)
tuple_param_quoted_none = ('tuple insert test quoted none', 'None')

cursor.execute(insert_statement_tuple, tuple_param_10);
cursor.execute(insert_statement_tuple, tuple_param_pure_none);
#cursor.execute(insert_statement_tuple, tuple_param_quoted_none);

dic_param_10 = {'exercise': 'dic_param_10', 'rpe': 19}
dic_param_None = {'exercise': 'dic_param_None', 'rpe': None}
dic_param_quoted = {'exercise': 'dic_param_None', 'rpe': 'None'}

cursor.execute(insert_statement_dic, dic_param_10);
cursor.execute(insert_statement_dic, dic_param_None);
#cursor.execute(insert_statement_dic, dic_param_quoted);


cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

To insert a "no value" (NULL) into a decimal column, I need to insert >None<  not >''< and not >'None'<

The implication is that when I build the dictionary of parameters from the comma-separated-value, I need to do a cleanup function that converst any empty string ('') into a a _builtin.None instead.  (unless I can figure out some way to make the CSV module automatically convert empty-strings ('') into a None.

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't about your value being empty, but about an error in your query. The error message just gives you a hint to where in the query the parse error happened, and that's on the `''`.

If you print `cursor._executed` after the query you'll see it better, it should show you something like:

`INSERT INTO ... VALUES ( ..., ''`

As you can see the real problem is that your query is missing a closing parenthesis, it should be:

```
insert_statement = ("INSERT INTO mydb.sets_ledger "
     "( exercise, weight, reps, rpe) "
     "VALUES ( %(Exercise)s, %(weight)s, %(reps)s, %(rpe)s )")
```

Comment: `_executed = 'INSERT INTO mydb.sets_ledger ( exercise, weight, reps, rpe) VALUES ( \\'Competition Back Squat\\', \\'60\\', \\'3\\', \\'\\’)'`     If I removed the "\" and feed that query directly into mysql, it complains about me inserting '' into rpe (which is a decimal(10,5)) `Error Code: 1366. Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'rpe' at row 1`